# How can I make my application find a third-party DLL using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have read many issues regarding and followed each one but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to include the [rdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) library into my project, but every time I run the application I am getting

> The program can't start because librdkafka.dll is missing from your computer.

I can clearly see that `librdkafka.dll` as well as `librdkafka.lib` exist in the same directory. I have added the include files to the project, and I have also added the `librdkafka.lib` to the additional directories in the Linker section. The project builds fine but it throws that error at runtime.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are using static linking. When you start debugging from VS, the current directory will be your project directory (If I remember correctly) not the path where your executable files are located

Comment: Make sure the DLL is visible in the [DLL search path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Asesh that seemed to work. I dumped all the dlls in the root directory but how can I change this so it looks in a specified directory?

Comment: Open your Project properties then choose ``Debugging`` from the left pane. Now on the right pane you should modify ``Working Directory``

Comment: A DLL that lives in the directory in which it was built is like a boomerang that doesn't come back.  It is a stick.  You must copy it into the same directory as the EXE that uses it.  That is automagic if the project that built the DLL is in the same solution and doesn't otherwise uses weirdo build settings.  Anything with a Unix background tends to be weirdo.  If it is not in the right spot then you must use xcopy /d in the EXE project's post-build event to ensure you have a usable copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in Visual Studio by default it is searching for dlls in the project directory and running the application on its own will try to find the dlls in the current working directory. Moving the dlls to this location seems to solve the issue.